# $\alpha$ can be the angle of which quadrants?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

Question:

> If $$\sin \alpha+\cos \alpha<0$$ then $\alpha$ can be the angle of which quadrants?

My attempts:

$$\sin \alpha+\cos \alpha<0 \Longrightarrow \sin
\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\alpha\right)<0$$

So I can choose $\left(\frac{ \pi}{4}+\alpha\right) \in \mathrm {III} \thinspace \text{quadrant}$ but $\alpha \in \mathrm {II} \thinspace \text{quadrant}$

Then I can choose $\left(\frac{ \pi}{4}+\alpha\right) \in \mathrm {IIII} \thinspace \text{quadrant}$ but $\alpha \in \mathrm {III} \thinspace \text{quadrant}$

So,  $x\in \mathrm {II, III} \thinspace \text{quadrants}$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Obviously, this is true for any $\pi \le \alpha \le \frac{3\pi}{2}$ as both sine and cosine are not positive. This will also be true for a part of second and fourth quadrant. Think of area $y+x<0$ on the coordinate plane

Comment: You almost had it, you had, $\pi/4 + \alpha \in (\pi,2\pi)$ which implies that $\alpha \in (\pi -\pi/4, 2\pi - \pi/4)$

Comment: Note that $\alpha$ **can** sometimes be in the same quadrant as $\alpha + \frac\pi4.$ You correctly identified the possibility of quadrants II and III but you missed a quadrant.

Answer (score 1):

A generalized solution for $\alpha$ can be obtained as follows
$$\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha<0$$
$$\sin\left(\alpha+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)<0\implies (2k-1)\pi<\left(\alpha+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)< 2k\pi$$
$$\frac{(8k-5)\pi}{4}<\alpha<\frac{(8k-1)\pi}{4}$$
$$\color{blue}{\alpha\in\left(\frac{(8k-5)\pi}{4}, \frac{(8k-1)\pi}{4}\right)}$$
Where, $k$ is any integer i.e. $k=0, \pm1, \pm2, \pm3,\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

Yeah your solution was going to be absolutely correct but u missed it in the last couple of lines.

I think the following solution would be more easy to understand:

sin a + cos a < 0

=> sin a < -cos a

=>tan a < -1

This means that tan a will be always negative.

And this happens in the II and IV quadrant.

Hence, the answer is II or IV quadrant.

PS-I ignored the fact that tan a should be also less than -1 because that would be true for a part of the II and IV quadrant (more precisely, if a diagonal is drawn throught the origin to divide those quadrants equally then a should be in either upper half of the second quadrant or lower half of the IV quadrant)

Comment: All the business about $\tan \alpha$ is wrong. You cannot assume that $\cos\alpha > 0,$ so the division by $\cos\alpha$ may not preserve the direction of the inequality. Hence you missed quadrant III.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(\alpha)=\sin(\alpha)+\cos(\alpha)$.  Its zeroes between $0$ and $2\pi$ are easily calulated to $\alpha=3\pi/4$ and $\alpha=7\pi/4$.  As $f$ is continuous it can't change sign on any of the intervals $]0,3\pi/4[$, $]3\pi/4,7\pi/4[$ and $]7\pi/4,2\pi[$. Thus you'll find out that $f$ is negative only on $]3\pi/4,7\pi/4[$.